# padding CSS window.print() @page not working

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to make a footer on my printed pages, but this *footer* stay over the content on page. I want to set a **padding-bottom** with the footer height but when I add padding-bottom on *@page* **css** nothing change.

How can I use **padding-bottom** on *@page* **css**?

Answer (score 0):

use @media print instead of @page, why?

This is @page browswer support:

[image]

#### This is `@media print`

> ## @media print
>
> Intended for paged material and for documents viewed on screen in print preview mode. Please consult the section on paged media, and the media section of the Getting Started tutorial for information about formatting issues that are specific to paged media.
>
> [image]
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

```js
function printData() {
  window.print();
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  printData();
})
```

```css
@media print {
  div {
    color: green;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./haha.css" media="print, screen"/> -->


<div>
  test print 1
</div>
<div>
  test print 2
</div>
<div>
  test print 3
</div>
<div>
  test print 4
</div>


<button>Print me</button>
```